# Best way to run several heavy processes in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have an indeterminate number of csv files. I want to back them up, then process them and save the result in the same file. The process is kind of heavy and it involves manipulating the values in the rows and columns, performing some search, adding values, etc.
Since it is heavy I would like to do it concurrently as much as possible.

I have the following code

```
import concurrent.futures
import pandas as pd
import os

def process_csv(file_path):
    # Modify the file name for backup
    backup_file_path = file_path.replace('.csv', '_BACK.csv')
    
    # Backup the file
    os.rename(file_path, backup_file_path)
    
    # Process the CSV file 
    df = pd.read_csv(backup_file_path)
    my_heavy_process(df)
    
    # Save the processed DataFrame to a new file
    result_file_path = file_path.replace('.csv', '_result.csv')
    df.to_csv(result_file_path, index=False)

# List of CSV files to process. It is supposed that I am going
# to read it dynamically from a folder
csv_files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv', 'file4.csv', 'file5.csv']

# Create a ThreadPoolExecutor with max_workers set to the number of files for parallel processing
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(csv_files)) as executor:
    # Submit each CSV file for processing
    futures = {executor.submit(process_csv, file): file for file in csv_files}

    # Wait for all tasks to complete
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

As an alternative I am thinking

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(csv_files)) as executor:
    # Submit each CSV file for processing
    futures = {executor.submit(process_csv, file): file for file in csv_files}

    # Wait for all tasks to complete
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

I am doubting which would be the best option. My process reads and writes files but I don't know if to say if the task is I/O bound. And I am guessing it *is* CPU bound
(I mean `my_heavy_process` is not I/O bound, but `process_csv` involves read/write files)

Another doubt I have is how should I set the `max_workers`. What happens if I have say 10 files or if I have 40 files? should it change?

Comment: `max_workers=len(csv_files))` is almost certainly not reasonable

Comment: in any case, have you done any *profiling to compare the two different approaches*?

Comment: I wanted to understand first how to discern what is CPU bound and what is I/O bound in this case.(I am still preparing the data)

Comment: Why backup the file and also save it post processing to a new location?

Comment: unless it is totally lopsided, e.g., you are just writing text, ro you aren't doing any I/O at all, then you have to rely on *empirical testing*

Comment: I see. Isn't a criteria on how to select the appropriate `max_workers`?

Comment: @KansaiRobot just leave `max_workers` empty, and the default will be relative to the number of CPU cores. You will not generally see any performance benefit from having more than that. If that is too many, and some run idle, it will only consume a little extra RAM without slowing down the other processes too much (assuming the task is much greater than the overhead of starting the processes in the first place).